# Anyone know how to explain this code? （print prime number)

Tags: java

```
int max = 100;
    String result="";

    // loop through the numbers one by one
    for (int i = 1; i<max; i++) {
        boolean isPrimeNumber = true;

        // check to see if the number is prime
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                isPrimeNumber = false;
                break; // exit the inner for loop
            }
        }
        // print the number if prime
        if (isPrimeNumber) {
           result=result+i+",";//used to holding the value for i
        }
        lblDisplay.setText(""+result);//used to holding the value for i
    }
}
```

first i initial the value of i as 1 and the system check if the 1 is less than 100...it will proceed....
later the j value initial as 2, if the j value is less than i, the system will loop....but 2 is larger than 1..why the system still can generate result? can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Line by line, what don't you understand?

Comment: You need to take several hours to read some (or several) good introductory books on Java programming. Then, try on your computer, and use some debugger to step by step in the code (or at least add some printing statements).

Comment: You want to print prime numbers form this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 1 is a special number and it not comes under the prime number so you have to separately write condition for 1 inside the outer loop :

```
    if(i == 1)
       isPrimeNumber = false;
```

And change the inner loop 
from 
`for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)` 
To 
`for (int j = 2; j <= i/2 ; j++)`